# How to LIMIT number of different choices in my model that user can save? - Python Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have model UserDraft. Inside that model I have pick_id with different choices represented in numbers when u go into Django Admin. I want each choice to be limited to max 5 times for each user to be picked.

For example in this code I want to have user1, 1, hero1, user1, 1, hero2, etc....Also i would love to restrict that you cant pick same hero twice.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User
from heroes.models import Hero
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class UserDrafts(models.Model):
    FIRST = "1"
    SECOND = '2'
    THIRD = '3'
    PICK_ID = [
        (FIRST, 1),
        (SECOND, 2),
        (THIRD, 3),
    ]
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_id")
    pick_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PICK_ID)
    hero_id = models.ForeignKey(Hero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__class__.objects.filter(user_id=self.user_id).count() >= 5:
            raise ValidationError('Maximum five picks are allowed per user')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "UserDraft"
        verbose_name_plural = "UserDrafts"
```

This save method that I used only limits user to pick more then 5 times. But I also want to be able to restrict choices for each choice to be picked 5 times per 1 user...So maximum number of picks will be 15. 5 pick_id`s will be 1(FIRST), 5 will be 2(SECOND), and 5 will be 3(THIRD).

I searched everything and I coudn`t find solution.

Also I`m using postgresql as my database.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don`t understand what I mean you can ask me here. I really need this solution for my app.

Comment: I think i will need 1 more table in order to do this...I`m not sure.

Comment: I would suggest to create a [Model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and then to take inputs use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) for Hero. Create a [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#writing-validators) to check weather your hero field contains 5 values or not, set it on form and then override form save() method for saving the values. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I will try that today. Thanks for reply. I will post answer and solution if I get it right